# Powershell New-ADUser set as enable

Tags: powershell

So i'm trying to create a list of new users in powershell on my windows server 2012 r2. I want the users name as Mike, Linda, Kurt. I run the following command

```
New-ADUser Kurt -enabled
```

I get an error as that does not work. I know that this command exists and works

```
New-ADUser Kurt
```

Is there a command to create a new user and set it to enabled without setting a password to it? I'm a beginner at powershell

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the `$true` value to the `-Enabled` flag, like so:

```
New-ADUser Kurt -Enabled $true
```

This is because the `-Enabled` flag expects a boolean value (true, false) to be sent to it.